# How to get a name of class that calls static function in php

Tags: php

I have:

```
public class MyCaller { 

  //Some code
  MyFinalClass::staticFunction();
}

final class MyFinalClass {
  public static staticFunction(){
    echo "I want this to be printing MyCaller or any other class when it calls the function."

}
```

How would I achieve that? If there is a way I could implicitly pass the calling class as some sort of default argument that I never have to hardcode in I would be fine with that too, but I don't want to have to manually put it in every single time.

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) seems to describe a case when I have inheritance, which is not the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that the only way to achieve this without using an explicit argument or inheritance is to pop the second entry from a call to `debug_backtrace()`:

```
final class MyFinalCalss
{
    public static function staticFunction()
    {
        echo "called from: " . debug_backtrace()[1]['class'] . "\n";
    }
}
```